# Organize multiple Webpack entry file dependencies

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack, ecmascript-6, node-modules

How to organize JS reusable components with their own dependencies in 3rd part bundles (e.g. `vendor/` subdirectories) with webpack different entry files/configs?

**Description:**

I have following structure with entrypoints and components

```
app/
  assets/
    index.js
  package.json
  webpack.config.js

vendor/
  my-utils-bundle/
    assets/
      components/
        MyMath.js
    package.json
    webpack.config.js
```

In my **includable within different entry files/webpack configs** `MyMath.js` components  there's `node_modules/` dependency to package e.g. `mathjs` with following line:

```
import { pi, pow, round, sqrt } from 'mathjs'

....some code below...
```

P.S. `mathjs` dependency package provided in this bundle (`vendor/my-utils-bundle/package.json`)

Then when i run `yarn dev` to compile my assets in `app/assets/index.js` there's following error:

```
"./vendor/my-utils-bundle/assets/components/MyMath.js" contains a reference to the file "mathjs".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.
```

**Question:**

How can i use this `MyMath.js` components as includable class in `app/assets/index.js` and maybe also in other "bundles" (e.g. `vendor/my-other-bundle`)?

Looks that I could install this `mathjs` dependency also in `app/package.json` but then it seems that on application level i should think about bundles JS dependencies that sounds not as the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [open question](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/5) that has been going on pretty much since the launch of Encore. Even earlier, given that according to the [best practices for bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#vendors), third party dependencies shouldn't be distributed, and left for the app to manage.

That being said, [there is *at least* one bundle (foxy)](https://packagist.org/packages/foxy/foxy) that attempts to solve this, by hooking into the `composer` commands and merge dependencies when packages are installed/updated.

From its README (emphasis mine):

> Foxy focuses solely on **automation of the validation, addition,
> updating and deleting of the dependencies in the definition file of
> the asset package**, while restoring the project state, as well as PHP
> dependencies if NPM or Yarn terminates with an error.
>
> Foxy **retrieves the list of all Composer dependencies to inject the
> asset dependencies in the file package.json**
>
> [...]
>
> Given that Foxy does not manipulate any asset
> dependencies, and let alone the version constraints, this allows NPM
> or Yarn to solve the asset dependencies without any intermediary

Comment: Thanks for the reference, didn't see this issue!